# Connected sum of Torus and Klein bottle.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If we look at the polygons of these spaces and we cut out a piece and glue it together like so, [image]
[image]
[image]

Do we lose any information when we compute the fundamental group using CW complex method described in Hatcher. Like this the wedge of 4 circles with the relation on the 2-cell.

Comment: The fundamental group of a wedge sum is the free product of each fundamental group

Comment: I understand that, but doing the gluing construction do we lose information? Compared to using Van Kampens Theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by "lose information"?

Comment: More so, does gluing lose a possible relation or something. My class barely touched upon connected sums, but this problem came up on our homework. This was the best way I could answer it.